# Undesired results while merging list and tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

So, I have,

```
fo = {'current': [[1,23],[3,45],[5,65]]}
pl = {'current': [(2,30),(3,33),(5,34)]}

total = {}
for i in fo,pl:             
    for j in i:             
        if total.get(j):    
            total[j] += i[j]
        else:               
            total[j] = i[j]
```

So, I expected,

```
total = {'current': [[1,23],[3,45],[5,65],(2,30),(3,33),(5,34)]}.
```

I understand that this is merging list and tuples.

```
But why does, fo =  {'current': [[1,23],[3,45],[5,65],(2,30),(3,33),(5,34)]} ??
```

Any hints ? Is merging list and tuples are problem? I think, both are lists and lists are mutable and tuple is not. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you're using the `+=` operator.  This modifies the list in place.  In your code, you end up with a reference to `fo['current']` stored in the `total` dictionary.  When you modify it from `total`, the list `fo` also sees the modification *because they are the same list*.

In this case, I'd probably use a `defaultdict`:

```
import collections
fo = {'current': [[1,23],[3,45],[5,65]]}
pl = {'current': [(2,30),(3,33),(5,34)]}
total = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in fo,pl:
    for key in d:
        total[key].extend(d[key])

total.default_factory = None #allow KeyErrors to happen

print total # defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'current': [[1, 23], [3, 45], [5, 65], (2, 30), (3, 33), (5, 34)]})
print fo  # {'current': [[1, 23], [3, 45], [5, 65]]}
print pl  # {'current': [(2, 30), (3, 33), (5, 34)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fo = {'current': [[1,23],[3,45],[5,65]]}
pl = {'current': [(2,30),(3,33),(5,34)]}

total = {}
for i in fo,pl:             
    for j in i:             
        if total.get(j):    
            total[j] += i[j] # in this step you actually modified the  list fo['current']` 
                             # it is equivalent to fo['current'] += i[j]
        else:               
            total[j] = i[j]  # this step simply creates a new 
                             # reference to the list fo['current']

            print fo['current'] is total[j]
            #prints True as both point to the same object
```

A quick fix is to assign a shallow copy to `total`:

```
total[j] = i[j][:]
```